# List of third party libraries to use flex development

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

What are all the third party libraries available to use in flex application. I would like to use graphical charts and advanced datagrid which had more features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

List of Frameworks & Tools:

- http://flex.apache.org/community-3rdparty.html

Charts

- Elixir: http://www.roguewave.com/products-services/visualization/elixir
- Axiis: http://www.axiis.org/